# Linq filter part of the date

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an Input and a datatable, when the user type in that input I filter data on KeyUp depending on what the user typed in. just like datatables.net but it is from scratch for learning.

The datatable has 3 columns fullname (string), city (string) and dateofbirth (datetime).

I want if the user type for example: "2/" it will give him all the DOB's that has 2/ in them. so far this is my code (I tried many but none worked).

```
    var data = _context.Person.Where(p => p.DateOfBirth.Value
                       .ToString("d").Split()[0].Contains(SearchQuery)).ToList();
```

// Split() to remove the time part.

And:

```
var data = _context.Person.Where(p => p.DateOfBirth.Value
                           .ToString().Contains(SearchQuery)).ToList();
```

But both giving me an exception: 'Translation of method System.DateTime.ToString' failed

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `Person`?

Comment: If `DateOfBirth` is a datetime use `.Day`

Comment: class Person {
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public string Fullname { get; set; }
  public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

Comment: Ooof.. I have a doubt this will work out well. I think you should refine your requirements rather than try and code this.. If the user types `2/` and you want to return birthdates like 2002/11/31, 2010/12/31, 2000/2/11, and you wanna do it on every keypress... Ugh

Comment: @Charlieface but What if the user continued typing '2/02/' because I am like showing data while the user is typing.

Comment: @CaiusJard can you please give me a hint, what do you mean?

Comment: You need to validate the input. Split on \ symbol and convert to int, or something.like that

Comment: The DateTime "d" for parse and ToString() is different.  When you use parse "d" means a day can be either one or two digits.  When you use ToString() you must use two d's "dd" since some days have one digit and other two digits.

Comment: Unless you're gonna impose some constraints on this (which don't really make sense) I flat out wouldn't do it. Make it an exact date search (user must type full date), or an interval search (user types eg dec, or 2002, or 15th to find all people on those date parts), but not a "user can type some text that looks like part of a date so i'll convert every date to a string and full text search it". On every keypress. No

Comment: you're right about 2002/11/31, 2010/12/31, 2000/2/11 part, this looks ugly I will change it to onSubmit instead.

Comment: You should also consider what happens when `DateOfBirth` is null

Comment: The error message is fairly specific. The overload of `System.DateTime.ToString` that takes a format string as a parameter cannot be translated into SQL by the query provider.

Answer (score 1):

When you use LINQ-to-entities, your C# code isn't actually executed. It is parsed. The runtime will parse the C# code as an *expression* and translate each symbol into some portion of a SQL string. It then sends this string to the database to be executed on the server. The server doesn't support the same kinds of date formatting, so your method call expression is not supported; there is no way to translate it into a SQL string.

However, the bigger problem here is that **you should not be hitting the database with every keystroke**; that is going to cause problems.

Instead, hit the database only once, when you load the form. Cache the list in memory. You can do this by calling `ToList`. Store the results in a member variable.

```
List<Person> _data;

void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _data = _context.Person.ToList();
}
```

Now that you have a local copy, you can use that instead of calling the database. And because your LINQ query doesn't have to be translated into a SQL statement, you can use any c# method you want.

```
void SearchQuery_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     var data = _data.Where(p => p.DateOfBirth.Value
                   .ToString("d").Split()[0].Contains(SearchQuery)).ToList();
     Display(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LIKE` statement which will get close to achieving what you want.

```
var data = _context.Person.Where(p => EF.Functions.Like(p.DateOfBirth, $"%{searchquery}%")).ToList();
```

A problem will be that if you are saving the dates as a `DateTime`, `DateTime2` or `DateTimeOffset` field then their representation in the database will be different to the string representation that you've entered. i.e. they probably won't have the '/' in them (although it's impossible to say since you don't mention your database technology).

Answer (score 0):

If you load the table to memory first by calling eg `context.person.ToList()` your method should work, and shouldn't fail converting `DateTime` to a `string`.

I'd suggest the following:

```
_context.Person.ToList().Where(p => p.DateOfBirth.Value
                           .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Contains(SearchQuery)).ToList();
```